# Groovy - The assignment of a string , to a variable of type int results in a number

Tags: variables, groovy, assign

Assigning empty string or string with letters results in GroovyCastException.Assigning a string with number values results in a number.What operation is happening here?

```
    int var_1 = 2;
    println var_1 // 2
    var_1 = ""
    println var_1 // GroovyCastException

    int var_1 = 2;
    println var_1 // 2
    var_1 = "2"
    println var_1 // 50
```

What operation/s results in 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considering "2" as a *single character* string, and assigning that character's Unicode value (U+0032 = '2') to the variable. So for example, I suspect if you do this:

```
var_1 = "A"
println var_1
```

you'll see 65 on the console

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like this

```
var_1 = "2"
println var_1
```

Then the Unicode value corresponding to the character "2" got printed, which is 50.
Similarly if you will try to print the unicode value of "B" or "C" then you will get 66 or 67 as the results.

You can print a result 50 by doing this:

```
int var_1 = "2"
println var_1
```